Parsing of floating point numbers with error on truncated precision
I am writing a parser for a LIN Description File(LDF). In a LDF file there may be floats. Currently I have a lexer that produces following question-relevant tokens:

Number: any character sequence composed of 0-9 digits stored in a ReadOnlySequence(Leading and trailing zeroes are preserved)
Dot: represents a '.' character without a value

Now whenever a floating point number is expected one of following sequences of tokens is expected:

Number -> Dot -> Number
Number

Now with the information I can get from these tokens I could create a Span of chars that has the digits of both Number tokens separated with a '.' or simply a Span of chars that has the digits of the Number. I can then call double.TryParse with the newly created Span.
Now I am concerned about the precision truncating nature of double.TryParse. It will return Infinity if the parsed number is to large for a double and I can check it and act accordingly. However, what I would like to do is somehow detect if the parsed number can't be represented "precisely enough"(truncating) and then inform the user that a floating point number of this precision is not supported and preferably fail this parsing instance.
What I mean by precisely enough is:

0.1 can't be precisely represented as a double or float for that matter. But it gets close enough. The loss of precision happens because this fraction is recurring in base 2. This should be allowed because that's the best we can do with any IEEE-754 number
1.123456789123456789 would result in 1.1234567891234568 where the last two digits are lost. I had hoped that the TryParse function method would fail in this case since the input is too precise. This is not the case. I am looking for a workaround where I can detect a loss of precision caused by an invalid value rather than because of limitation of floating point numbers themselves.

Is there a way to detect such an overflow in significant digits? I need to do this without any managed heap allocations.
The rationale behind this is that whoever wrote the LDF file meant something by including this many significant digits. If some of those digits were to be truncated this might cause the program to not behave correctly based on the input file. This is why I want to consider this an error. Potentially I could limit the amount if decimal digits(Sum of ReadOnlySequence lengths) to something that would definitely not overflow but then very small numbers with many 0s before significant digits would be false positives. I hope someone can share some insights into this.

decimal has 28-29 digits precision. See: Floating-point numeric types (C# reference).

Yes I know about Decimal but aside from the fact that I do not require its accuracy it still doesn't provide me with the information if the parsed value was two precise. decimal.TryParse("1.123456789123456789123456789123456789") still succeeds even though precision is lost.

I cannot imagine why you need this precision for network descriptions. At least decimal will not produce phantom digits at the end like double.

I most probably don't need so much precision but I don't know what file will be parsed so I wanted to sanitize it and don't allow any operations on truncated values caused by a user error.

You can convert the parsed number back to a string and compare it to the original. But your approach will not work if the are numbers like 1.2e-3 (if they are allowed in LDFs).

Real numbers in LDFs are always in the format "integral.fraction" i.e. no exponents. The string method would work but it involves managed heap allocations which I should avoid if possible. I was hoping there are some mathematical properties one could use to determine loss of precision during parsing of a decimal formatted string.

An interesting problem.  12345.734734783487510867416858673095703125 can be represented exactly.  12345.734734783487510867416858673095703124 cannot.

At a handwaving heuristic level you only need to check numeric values that are at least 16+ digits long including the decimal point. Some of them might still be sufficiently accurately represented by the mantissa of a double precision FP number. The way to tell would be convert suspect cases to both double and Decimal then subtract the FP version promoted to Decimal to see if the (delta/abs_value) is acceptable to you.

Your question does not define what “close enough” is. One thing you can do is convert the resulting floating-point number to decimal with the same number of digits after the decimal point as the input, as with sprintf(buffer, "%.*f", 18, x) for input “1.123456789123456789”. If that does not produce the same digits as in the input, aside from leading zeros, you could declare the number not “close enough.” But what qualifies as “close enough” depends on what is going to be done with these numbers, which you have not said. For example, if the goal is merely to remember them and reproduce them…

… later, then the test above is sufficient, provided you also store how many digits after the decimal point there were. But if calculations are going to be done with the numbers, then errors are likely to compound, and what is “close enough” depends on both the numbers and the calculations.
